# LoadingCache for a list of keys

Tags: caching, guava, google-guava-cache

I have a downstream service which takes the list of ids and return the data for the ids. I am exploring Guava LoadingCache to cache these values. But the loader in the LoadingCache accepts only one key. Are there any ways to use the list of keys.

Comment: Which list of key? When you call cache.get("foo"), how can the cache know that later, maybe, you will also want the values for "bar" and "baz"? Is that list of key constant?

Comment: Basically, i want to do cache.getAll(listOfKeys). But loader.load is taking only one key. It means the downstream service should be called for every key.

Comment: And is that listOfKeys always the same?

Comment: Not all the keys will be same. Some of the keys will be same and some are new keys. I want to collect the new keys and make a service call. For the old keys want to take the data from cache.

Comment: I did a small experimentation, it looks like this can be done by using getAll and loadAll APIs. https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#from-a-cacheloader

Comment: @NavinGv Why not post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a small experimentation, it looks like this can be done by using getAll and loadAll APIs. https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#from-a-cacheloader

Sample code available in https://github.com/gvnavin/CachingExperimentations